# Discard RewriteRule in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

There are 2 RewriteRules for permalink in php.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*).htm index.php [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*).html index.php [NC,QSA,L]
```

I need to browse a static html file:

```
/uploads/themes/mail-signature/mail-signature.html
```

But when I enter `http://example.com/uploads/themes/mail-signature/mail-signature.html` it's showing `index.php`.

How can I discard these rules?

Comment: Either add a RewriteCond (before each rule) that checks if the requested URI is _not_ that, or add another RewriteRule before the two existing ones, that matches that exact path, but does no rewriting at all (`-` as the substitution), and uses the `L` or `E` flag to step out of the process at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^(.*).htm index.php [NC,QSA,L]
> RewriteRule ^(.*).html index.php [NC,QSA,L]
> ```

Your 2nd rule isn't actually doing anything anyway, since any `.html` requests will be caught by the first rule. So, the second rule can be removed.

You then add a condition to the first rule that excludes the specific URL you are trying to access. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/uploads/themes/mail-signature/mail-signature\.html$
RewriteRule \.html?$ index.php [NC,L]
```

The `QSA` flag is not required here, as any query string will be passed through by default.

The `^(.*)` prefix on your `RewriteRule` *pattern* is not required since you aren't using this backreference.

You should backslash escape any literal dots in the regex, eg. `\.htm`, otherwise you are matching any character, eg. "xhtm". And presumably you only want to match URLs that end in `.htm` or `.html`? Your original regex would match "htm" anywhere in the requested URL.